# Did NATO Air Forces start shooting down Russian fighter jets?

Tags: aviation, war, russia, syria, turkey

In the beginning of October, several news appeared claiming that Russian fighter jets intruded the air space of Turkey. They have been intercepted and escorted away from Turkish air space, but no fire was open.

On October, 10, British news agency Express published an [article](http://www.express.co.uk/news/world/611157/Russia-Turkey-jet-plane-shot-down-airspace-Syria-ISIS-Islamic-State) that claims that Turkish Air Forces have (finally) started shooting down Russian fighters who intrude Turkey air space:

> *A **Russian jet has been shot down** by Turkish forces after it flew into the country's airspace, according to as yet unconfirmed reports circulating on social media.*

This article *only refers social media and eyewitnesses*. It also says that no official confirmation has been received:

> *Express.co.uk has contacted the Turkish government and the Russian military but neither could be reached for comment.*

Later on the same day, a Turkish agency Teknodeck has also published [a similar article](http://www.teknodeck.com/turkiye-rusya-jetini-dusurdu-son-dakika-9659.html).

On October 11, British Daily Star has published [an article](http://www.dailystar.co.uk/news/latest-news/469414/RAF-Tornados-missile-Putin-Syria-UK-tensions-strikes-Islamic-State) that says:

> *RAF fighter jets will be armed with air-to-air missiles and have been **given the green light to shoot down hostile Russian planes**.*

But again, the article provided with no credible sources.

So, the question is: **Are there any better sources confirming or denying the events claimed?**

Besides of the above, I think it's related. I'm a bit confused about the difference: are *only Turkish* RAF allowed to counteract the hostile Russian jets, or the *entire NATO* Air Forces?

In the case if the claimed events are true, I'm also curious about whether or not the downed plane was „formally“ Russian, since there were numerous reports that all the Russians aircraft, including the Su-25s and the Su-34s, were **removed the standard Russian Air Force markings** and the typical Red Star. So the Russian officials could easily claim that the jets were not Russian, but instead belonged to ISIS, Assad, or any other Russian ally.

[image: A Russian fighter jet]

A Russian fighter jet with Air Force markings painted over. [Image taken from ria.ru](http://ria.ru/world/20151002/1295269108.html), an official Russian agency.

Comment: I wish.. Unfortunately I don't know the answer

Comment: The Daily Mail reported that Turkey had shot down a Russian aircraft a day or two ago.  But it's the Daily Mail and therefore suspect by default.

Comment: @GordonM I did not refer Daily Mail for this very reason.

Comment: The last I heard was that it was an unidentified drone and no one has yet acknowledged it is theirs.

Comment: @MarkHurd, yes. You may find it interesting that Ukrainian forces [also claim](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=152281461789703&id=100010235495201) that they have downed two Russian drones **of the same construction** over the occupied Eastern Ukraine in May 2014 and July 2014. Anyway, there are no official responses on this.

Comment: Wit the events of the last week, this question got a new turn, and everyone who has a TV can probably easily answer it...